# Changing styles when scrolling React

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I want to add the scrolling effect. At the start, the elements have the `opacity: 0.2` property. When element is reached in the browser window, it is to replace the property with `opacity: 1`. At this moment, when I scroll, all elements change the property to `opacity: 1`. How to make this value when element is reached in the browser, the rest of the elements have the property `opacity: 0.2`

```
class QuestionListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      opacity: 0.2,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      this.setState({
        opacity: 1,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { question } = this.props;
    const { opacity } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <li
          key={question.id}
          className="Test__questions-item"
          style={{ opacity: `${opacity}` }}
          ref={
            (listener) => { this.listener = listener; }
          }
        >
          <p>
            {question.question}
          </p>
          <QuestionAnswerForm />
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want effect like this https://anemone.typeform.com/to/jgsLNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper solution could look like this. Of course, this is just a concept. You can fine-tune the activation/deactivation logic using props from [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) other than `top` (e.g. height, bottom etc).
Important that you should not set the component's state on every single scroll event.

```js
const activeFromPx = 20;
const activeToPx = 100;

class ScrollItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.handleScroll();
  };
  
  handleScroll = () => {
    const { top } = this.wrapRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (top > activeFromPx && top < activeToPx && !this.state.isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: true });
    }
    if ((top <= activeFromPx || top >= activeToPx) && this.state.isActive) {
      this.setState({ isActive: false });
    }
  }
  
  setWrapRef = ref => {
    this.wrapRef = ref;
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        className={`scroll-item ${isActive && 'scroll-item--active'}`}
        ref={this.setWrapRef}
        >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class ScrollExample extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scroll-wrap">
        <ScrollItem>foo</ScrollItem>
        <ScrollItem>bar</ScrollItem>
        <ScrollItem>eh</ScrollItem>
      </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ScrollExample />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.scroll-wrap {
  height: 300vh;
  background: lightgray;
  padding-top: 55px;
}

.scroll-item {
  height: 60vh;
  background: lightcyan;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.scroll-item--active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how did you set these numbers 20 and 100? Why these numbers?

Comment: it is just a quick example. The item is active if its top edge is between 20 and 100 px distance from top of viewport. But you should find out some more advanced method like this, considering the window height etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can include an *isInViewport*-like implementation as this one: https://gist.github.com/davidtheclark/5515733 then use it on your component.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
    if (isElementInViewport(event.target) {
      this.setState({
        opacity: 1,
      });
    }
  });
};
```

There's also read-to-use react-addons for this: https://github.com/roderickhsiao/react-in-viewport